# Hide a usercontrol in a usercontrol from another form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a user control named `Meeting` which is inside a user control `P2` inside `Form2`. From `Form1` I call a function named `Update` in `P2` :

```
public void Update1()
{
    meeting1.Visible = false;
}
```

So from Form 1 I use :

```
    P2 p = new P2();
    p.Update();
```

And it does nothing. If I use the function from `P2` directly it works but it doesn't work if I try to use it from Form1. If i add a `MessageBox` inside the function, the MessageBox works but codes regarding `meeting` doesn't.

Comment: OK, you have an instance of `P2`. If it calls `Update()` on itself, that happens. Now you create *a totally different new instance of `P2`*, which you know is new because you said `new P2()` to create it. When you call `Update()` on that, you are not calling `Update()` on the other `P2`. Do you see?

Comment: Hmm, I understand. So How should I proceed?

Comment: What creates `Form2`? He needs to keep a reference to it and expose it for use by `Form1`. If `Form1` creates it, that's easy.

Comment: `Form2` is the standard WinForm which runs when I hit F5

Comment: Who creates `Form1`, then?

Comment: `meeting` creates `Form1`

Comment: Ahh, right, you said that. Thanks.

Comment: It comes like this: `Form2` opens. You click a buttonand you open `P2` then you click another button and `meeting` is opened. there you click something and `Form1` opens

Comment: Is P2 newly created when you click the button, or is it there already and you just make it visible? Same with Meeting; is it really there all along, just not visible?

Comment: They are there but they are not visible

Comment: That makes it easy.

Comment: :DD how do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do: Give Meeting an `UpdateButtonAction` property. We'll have it pretend that it never heard of P2, because dependencies or something.

```
public Action UpdateButtonAction { get; set; }
```

At the end of P2's constructor, assign this to it.

```
this.meeting1.UpdateButtonAction = () => this.Update();
```

And then we also give Form1 an identical property:

```
public Action UpdateButtonAction { get; set; }
```

We have two copies of the action property because I'm assuming that you haven't created an instance of Form1 yet at this point. If you have, that simplifies matters.

I don't know when Form1 is trying to do this; it sounds like an update button kind of a thing, but we can change that if I guessed wrong.

So when `Meeting` creates Form1, it passes along its `UpdateButtonAction` action that its parent `P2` gave it. This code is somewhere in Meeting (I'm guessing how it creates Form1, let me know if this doesn't adapt well to what you're really doing):

```
var form1 = new Form1();

form1.UpdateButtonAction = this.UpdateButtonAction;

//  Or whatever
form1.ShowDialog();
```

Form1 can invoke that action at will. This line will call that Action lambda that was assigned in `P2`'s constructor.

```
this.UpdateButtonAction?.Invoke();
```

You could also just pass in a reference to `P2` the same way, but this is nicer because OOP etc.

Comment: The type name 'meeting1' does not exist in the type etc at line `this.P2.meeting1.UpdateButtonAction = () => this.Update();`

Comment: Form2 owns an instance of `P2`, right? What's that instance of `P2` called? Come to think of it, lt's likely to be `p21`, is that right?

Comment: P2 owns meeting1 but the auto-complete only shows 4 Control and Docks things after `this.P2.`

Comment: yes, it's p21 but i can not write p21. it doesn't show up at auto complete and gives me an error

Comment: That sounds like `p21` is actually a member of something other than `Form2`. You are doing this *in* `Form2`, right?

Comment: No.. I have Form2 and from ToolBox i added the usercontrol and it became p21. From Form2_load I can access p21 but not from the end of constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I am in Form 2

Comment: And there is another thing. You wrote this.Update() but the update function is in P2 not in Form2

Comment: If `p21` is in scope in any non-static method of `Form2`, including constructor s, it's equally in scope in any other method or constructor. This isn't a static constructor by any chance?

Comment: @RobertVlasiu Whoops, so I did. That kills two birds with one stone, half a minute while I update my answer.

Comment: `    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(string role, string name)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.role = role;
            this.name = name;
        }`

Comment: @RobertVlasiu OK, I rewrote the answer. Now P2 gives Meeting the Action, and Form2 isn't involved because it doesn't need to be.